# grunt: convert images to base64 and insert into html

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Used `grunt` and `grunt-preprocess` to prepare my html files.

How can I replace image tags (`<img src="/some/image">`) to its `base64` inline copy

Comment: I think you may be interested in this article: [On Mobile, Data URIs are 6x Slower than Source Linking](http://www.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just used `grunt-base64` to convert image/icon to base64 file, and at `grunt-preprocess` use 
`<!-- @include my_base64_file -->`